# Can you help me identify the font used in this text that says "EXPERT WITNESS"?

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used in this image?

[image]

It is too squat to be Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, or any of the other typical non-serif fonts, and the image isn't crisp enough for me to make any headway on Identifont.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is Helvetica65 at 80 - 90% vertical scale:

[image]

Comment: Wow that does look pretty darn similar!

Comment: Pretty sure that's it - the capital "R" of Helvetica is pretty characteristic.  If it's not Helvetica, it's something trying very hard to be Helvetica.

It may be a slightly heavier weight than this though.